# Not able to run c# code with GstSharp Nuget package

Tags: c#, gstreamer

I want to execute basic code of GStreamer using GstSharp nuget package. The application build successful but at run time it throws error

> "Unable to load DLL 'libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll': The specified module
>   could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

then try to create Pipeline object. I am using GstSharp Nuget package but first statement throws the error. Is there any extra setting required after installing Nuget package GstSharp?

```
            // Build the pipeline
            var pipeline = Parse.Launch("playbin uri=https://download.blender.org/durian/trailer/sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4");

            // Start playing
            pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);

            // Wait until error or EOS
            var bus = pipeline.Bus;
            var msg = bus.TimedPopFiltered(Constants.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, MessageType.Eos | MessageType.Error);

            // Free resources
            pipeline.SetState(State.Null);
```

Comment: Maybe it is because of different runtime : f.e. You use netcore , and GstSharp is using net461.

Comment: I am using .net 4.5.2 I also tried .net 4.6.1 as target framework in Visual studio. can you please explain way to solve it

Comment: Looks like GstSharp is just a wrapper around gstreamer. Have You installed gstreamer ? https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html?gi-language=c

Comment: Also GstSharp lacks of documentation so I cannot tell which version of gstreamer should be installed. Maybe this libs can do https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp